# Java applet to display and play midi files

Tags: java, applet, midi

I am looking for a java applet to be embedded in a web page and be able to present notes or tabs based on midi files. I would also be very happy if it could be able to play these files. Does any of you know of such an applet? perhaps some kind of an open source project ongoing somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

[You don´t need an applet to play midi files in a browser.](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_browsersounds.asp)

Also, I found a small [MIDI Player Applet](http://www.pscode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=6236&lngWId=2), but haven't tested it myself.

Comment: But he also wants to be able to display the notes; it looks like he wants a midi visualizer, potentially with playback if available...

Comment: Yep Stobor, that's what I am looking for. Any such thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at Java FX, its designed for multimedia applications.

http://javafx.com/

Chances are someone has written something similar to what you are looking for.